# Change size of encrypted lvm parition

Tags: partition, dual-boot, gparted

I would like to reduce the size of my encrypted lvm partition (Ubuntu 20.04) in order to install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu. How would I do it?

GParted does not seem to work, I also tried a live USB. I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/448831/resizing-moving-lvm-volumes), but the post is 10 years old and I am a bit anxious to just try it out. I also found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=4530641), but that one is even older. What would be the way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Resizing a partition might fail, so there is a risk of losing your data. You should create a backup before trying this. If it fails, restore from your backup. Please [edit] your question and add more details in what way "GParted does not seem to work". Do you get an error message?  Does it prevent you from trying an operation?

Comment: Depends on what's in there... you have to shrink filesystem first, then LV, then PV, ... LUKS / nvme0n1p3 comes last. If it's too difficult, you can backup all files, re-create partitions from scratch, then restore.